# Procesos cíclicos paralelos y memoria en Python 2.x

Tags: python, ciclos, variables-globales

Estoy (para pasar el rato) intentando diseñar un videojuego en python, y me he encontrado frente a dos graves problemas.

- El primero es que se suceda un movimiento de forma cíclica, ininterrumpido por las acciones del jugador (como las flores en los juegos de pokémon, vaya).
  Su código sería:

  ```
  class tile (image, layer, position):


          def __init__ (self, image, layer, position):
              self.im = image
              self.ly = layer 
              self.pos = position
          def movement (self): 
              if len(self.im) == 2:
              while mapp.presence == True:
                  mapp.printt(self.im[0], self.pos)
                  time.sleep(0.1) 
                  mapp.printt(self.im[1], self.pos)
  ```

El scrip tendría que correr de forma paralela para que funcionare (que ese es mi mayor problema, pues temo que demasiados de éstos objetos en un mapa puedan ralentizar el procesador al usar threading). También necesito algo alternativo al time.sleep(0.1) porque me para ejecución. mapp.printt(image, position) es un método relativo al mapeo de la zona, que me permite mostrar una determinada imagen del tile en la posición del propio tile. mapp.presence es una variable de la misma clase que me indica si el personaje se encuentra en dicho mapa (y por tanto, el movimiento pararía al salir el personaje del mapa.

- El otro es más un pequeño tema acerca de usar variables globales: 
  ¿Cómo véis el uso de un archivo .py importado al propio documento que sirva exclusivamente para guardar datos, como si fuese una memoria?
  Os voy a pasar parte del código para que veáis a lo que me refiero. Primero la clase que me crea el objeto de índice  #0000001, sin flags (permanente y que no cambia con el transcurso de la aventura).

  ```
  class code(number, flags):


          def __init__(self, number, flags, events):
              self.nu = number
              self.fl = flags
              self.ev = events

          def allflags (self):
              k = 0
              z = False
              for e in flaglist:
                  for t in self.fl:
                      if e.status == t.status:
                          k += 1
              if k == len(self.fl) + 1:
                  z == True
                  return z


  class event (typ, imageset, messages, eventcode):


          def __init__ (self, typ, imageset, messages, eventcode):
              self.ty = typ
              self.im = imageset
              self.me = messages
              self.cod = eventcode
              if self.cod.allflags() == True:
                  self.st = 'ACTIVE'
              else:
                  self.st = 'INACTIVE'

          def do(self):
              if self.ty == 'item':
                  item(self.cod)
              elif list(self.ty).split('-').count('NT') == 1 :
                  faceplayer()
                  if typ == 'NPC-NTPK':
                      startbattle(self.cod)
                  elif typ == 'NPC-NTCH' or typ == 'NPC-NTCO':
                      changeflags(self.cod)
                      conversation(self.cod, self.me)
                  elif list(self.ty).split('-').count('TR') == 1:
                      startbattle(self.cod)'
  ```

El propio archivo estaría lleno de  objetos para ser construidos en el script principal utilizando clases. La idea de las clases (que se encuentran por ahora incompletas) es que lea de un fichero previo, llamémoslo memory.py el objeto, en nuestro caso, sería algo como:

```
"""
coding utf-8 etc.
"""
# Códigos de evento
COD0000001 = code('0000001', '')

# Eventos propiamente dichos
EV0000001 = event(NTCO, '', 'Holamundo', COD0000001)
```

¿Si lo estructuro así, qué problemas me puedo encontrar?

Siento si hay algún error de sintaxis en este texto, pero se me hace muy difícil transcribir código.

Comment: Hola Phazoning. Tu pregunta a mi parecer no está clara y está basada en opiniones. Para tu primera pregunta, trata de implementarlo y muestranos que problemas concretos o errores tienes. Respecto  a la segunda, has de reformularla para que no sea subjetiva. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: He intentado clarificar mi pregunta, aparte de añadir el código (parte de él) que pretendo utilizar